# What's a safe way to define Meteor server methods for use only in tests?

Tags: meteor

I want the methods to be available only for tests, and not in application code. For example, a method to delete any user. I don't want this capability in production code. But it's helpful in test code.

How would I add provide such a method in a test context while keeping it out of production code?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution:

Let's assume you create a package called `test-helpers`. In it, you create a function called `removeAllUsers` in the `TestHelpers` namespace.

Now in another package that needs `TestHelpers.removeAllUsers`, you can just do this:

```
Package.onTest(function(api) {
  api.use('TestHelpers', 'server');
});
```

Because we only included the package in `onTest`, it won't exist in your production code. Furthermore, we created a server-only function (not a method), so even if it did get exposed in production, it couldn't be called from a client.